# Update Git password after changing GitHub password

Tags: git, github

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the answers helped me, I've updated my password account on GitHub and now can't push anything on my GitHub repository.
I don't understand what I have to do to re-configure Git with my GitHub account, I'm pretty new to Git ...

Comment: Use keys, and never look back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on OS X? If so, you may need to reset your local credential storage to the new password. See: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: I just followed the instructions but when i enter github.com in keychain access.app I have no result

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user, you can try to find a file named password and delete it, which maybe located in path: c:/user/(your name)/appdat/local/source tree(or some other client name)/.

I have been there and know your feeling.